# Get json array nested within another json object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to loop through an array of photo objects in java, from the flickr api but cant seem to target the photo array because it is nested within a json object with page values as seen below.

```
{
    "page" : 1,
    "pages" : 10,
    "perpage" : 100,
    "total" : 1000,
    "photo" : [
        {photo objects}
    ]
}
```

I expect to get photo objects which i can then pass to a photos model class.

Comment: Do you use an available JSON parser, or are you parsing it by hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Vimukthi_R Thank you for researching duplicate question which may answer this question as well. But the question you found here isn't actually a suitable duplicate target, because the linked question is for Javascript, not Java like this one here.

Comment: Can you print the data that you receive? And add on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what library you are using, i personally use GSON and am going to base the example on that library.

this is how i would go about it:

```
if(json.has("photo"){
    JsonArray photoArray = json.get("photo").getAsJsonArray(); //get the full array
    for(int i = 0; i < photoArray.size(); i++){ //loop through all photo objects inside the array
        PhotoObject photoObject = photoArray.get(i);
        //do something with your objects
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using okhttp, but let me try and implement the above concept and see how that goes. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something like this:

```
//make the string into a JSONObject
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("ur Json string"); 

//get the JSONArray from the object
JSONArray array1 = obj.getJSONArray("photo");
```

`array1` is your JSON array. 
To get the JSON object, you can:

```
JSONObject photo1 = array1.getJSONObject(0); //get first element in the JSONArray
```

Then you can do mapping to map the `JSONObject` to your own `Photo` object.

Refer to:

JSONObject - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

JSONArray - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: I tried this but it does not work, not sure why why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use two classes for this,

**page values class**

```
class Response {
    private int page;
    private int pages;
    private int perpage;
    private int total;
    private List<Photo> photo; //List of photo objects

    //getters setters
}
```

**photo class**

```
class Photo {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    //getters setters
}
```

In your main class you can access photo objects using below code,

```
for (Photo p : response.getPhoto()) {
    System.out.println(p.id);
}
```